# I need Facebook Comment help

Tags: facebook

I have created an app tab to be used for a Facebook Page.  In This app I've embedded Facebook comments.  However, these comments are in random order.  I was wondering if there was a way to display these comments in the order that they were posted?

The code that I used to generate the Facebook comments is as follows

```
<fb:comments
   app_id="168848466497060"
   migrated="1"
   xid="thisisatestcomment"
   href="http://www.facebook.com/muskegonsummercelebration"
   num_posts="4"
   width="440px">
</fb:comments>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments/), it appears your only ordering option is setting `reverse` to true or false. I'm assuming the default is so-called 'top comments', but I can't imagine `reverse` would show the worst comments.